# React: - How to call an API multiple times and get data chunk by chunk

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Problem**

I have a scenario that need to call an API multiple times till get full data from server, Since the data is huge, server is sending the data chunk by chunk.

**Current Implementation**

Current implementation existing in GWT (Google web toolkit) and the scenario handled is, if the server taking time to collect the full data, will send a response with token id and 1st chunk of data. So that client will not get timeout and make another request with the latest token id. This continues process happens till client get full data.

**challenge in React part**

Currently i am planning with Redux and ReduxSaga implementation. But the challenge is how to hold the data without updating the state and make the repeated API call and wait till server respond full data.

Comment: i'm thinking, recursive function might helped.

Comment: can you use Socket to handle this type of requests?